# Require jwt for all api routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I have been searching through `nextjs` documentation and I found this thing.

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt"

const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // if using `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` env variable, we detect it, and you won't actually need to `secret`
  // const token = await getToken({ req })
  const token = await getToken({ req, secret })
  console.log("JSON Web Token", token)
  res.end()
}
```

[source](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#jwt-helper)

This gives you the possibility to get the authentication, but I don't know where to use it or how to implement it in all routes. I think it has to be in the `/api/auth/[...nextauth.js]` but I haven't found any information about it.

I have all my api routes inside api folder.

Help is needed, thanks in advance!

Comment: Sidenote, you don't need `[NEXTJS]` in the title if you tagged this with `next.js`; Stackoverflow does this automatically 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextjs 12 has a new [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware) feature, which is a good suit for your authentication, all you have to do is create `_middleware.js` file your `/pages` directory and export a middleware function.

```js
// pages/_middleware.js
// this function runs before every request.
export function middleware(req, ev) {
 // define your authentication logic here
  return new Response('Hello, world!')
}
```

the only downside is Native Node.js APIs are not supported.

Comment: it says pages/_middleware.js does it work the same if I put it under /api/_middleware.js?

Comment: yes my bad yeah its on the `/pages` directory

Answer (score 0):

Given your question is around API routes, You need API routes with middleware

The new *middleware* for pages can be confusing but this uses the incoming request for an `api` as an intermediary e (e.g: api/auth.js) that receives a `req` object that you can then further inspect for the token.

See their example using API Routes with Middleware (no `_middleware.js` involved.

It get the incoming request to `/api/cookie` and adds a `cookie` header

1. `pages/index.js` calls `/api/cookie` - this you will incorporate around your routes
2. `pages/api/cookie.js` acts as your api route handler
3. `pages/api/cookie.js` imports cookie logic (in your case `jwt` cookies

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-middleware

Answer (score 0):

```
// next.js middleware does not take res as argument
export default async function handler(req, ev) {
  console.log('what is ev',ev)
  const token = await getToken({ req, secret });
  // sinde you use jwt, you have to somehow extract userId
  const userId = await verifyToken(token);
  // you do not need to check for authentication if user wants to login
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  // static is folder that you Load images. You might use something else. if you dont add check, your images wont load
  if (
    pathname.includes("/api/login") ||
    userId ||
    pathname.includes("/static")
  ) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (!token && pathname !== "/login") {
    return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer I'll give it a try! Thanks